# How to repeat rows from a table with a hierarchical structure by the value of a specific column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table that defines the structure of the message. Each row contains information about what type of data can come, how long it is, and so on. Each row can be of a constant type (String, Integer, etc.) or a reference type, which means that it refers to another message. In other words, a message can contain  messages. When the type is a reference value, length information means that this type is repeated by that length. In conclusion, a message can be hierarchically defined.

I want to write a query that can serialize a hierarchically defined message and fetch it to depth one.

The problem is how to repeated with reference to a particular column (length information) in the hierarchical table.

I want to know how to repeat rows from a table with a hierarchical structure by the value of a specific column in Oracle 11g.

Abstractly defined sample table is below.

```
| ID | SEQ | TYPE | LENGTH | REF_ID |
|----|-----|------|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 1  | 2   | R    | 2      | 2      |
| 1  | 3   | V    |        |        |
| 1  | 4   | R    | 2      | 2      |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 2   | R    | 2      | 3      |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
```

If the TYPE column is 'R', this row is a reference type. This means that this row is replaced with rows with the ID shown in the REF_ID column.
For example

```
| ID | SEQ | TYPE | LENGTH | REF_ID |
|----|-----|------|--------|--------|
| 1  | 2   | R    | 2      | 2      |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 2   | V    |        |        |
```

ID '1' row is replaced with rows having ID '2'.

```
| ID | SEQ | TYPE | LENGTH | REF_ID |
|----|-----|------|--------|--------|
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 2   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 2   | V    |        |        |
```

At this time, it is desired to repeat the corresponding row by the value of the LENGTH column. However, the hierarchy and order must still be observed.

Querying a hierarchy from the table above is very simple, but it is not easy to iterate over the values in the column.

```
WITH DATA AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS SEQ, 'V' AS TYPE, NULL AS LENGTH, NULL AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS ID, 2 AS SEQ, 'R' AS TYPE, 2 AS LENGTH, 2 AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS ID, 3 AS SEQ, 'V' AS TYPE, NULL AS LENGTH, NULL AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS ID, 4 AS SEQ, 'R' AS TYPE, 2 AS LENGTH, 2 AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS SEQ, 'V' AS TYPE, NULL AS LENGTH, NULL AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 2 AS SEQ, 'R' AS TYPE, 2 AS LENGTH, 3 AS REF_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 1 AS SEQ, 'V' AS TYPE, NULL AS LENGTH, NULL AS REF_ID FROM DUAL 
)

SELECT *
  FROM DATA
 START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR REF_ID = ID
ORDER SIBLINGS BY SEQ
```

The final result for ID '1' I want to get from the above data is as follows. Only the rows with TYPE V are left in the final result, and the output is repeated as many times as defined in LENGTH.

```
| ID | SEQ | TYPE | LENGTH | REF_ID |
|----|-----|------|--------|--------|
| 1  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 1  | 3   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 2  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
| 3  | 1   | V    |        |        |
```

I have tried various ways to achieve this result, but I can not think of a pointed way. If you have a good idea, please share it.

Comment: What do you mean by "uses the ID of the row referenced in ROW_ID"? The ID column contains duplicates (for example: there are **two** rows with ID = 2), so the requirement as stated makes no sense. Please do not answer in a Comment; instead, edit the original post to clarify what you mean.